# How to install Xdebug on PhpStorm Apache 2 PHP 7.4

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, php-7.4

I've installed Xdebug and setup by this instruction:

Install Xdebug PHP:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y php7.4-xdebug
```

Find `xdebug.so`, then add the first one to php.ini:

```
sudo updatedb
locate xdebug.so
```

[image]

```
locate php.ini
```

[image]

Config php.ini:

```
sudo gedit /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
```

[image]

Then restart Apache web server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

PhpStorm settings and code:

[image]
[image]

Result and Xdebug Chrome extension enabled:

[image]

Did I miss anything? This setting works fine for me in PHP 7.2 and bellow but now on PHP 7.4 and it's not working any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP 7.4 you need xdebug.so with `20190902` in the path.

You can check that from `phpinfo()` output: and you will see the PHP API version there, at the very top:

**PHP 7.4:**

```
...
PHP API => 20190902
PHP Extension => 20190902
Zend Extension => 320190902
...
```

**PHP 7.2:**

```
...
PHP API => 20170718
PHP Extension => 20170718
Zend Extension => 320170718
...
```

Your `20131226` is for **PHP 5.6**.

You have to use extensions that were compiled to use the same API version.

So double check `phpinfo()` output: you need to confirm that right API version is used + that Xdebug is actually loaded and enabled (use `xdebug_info()` for Xdebug v3; for Xdebug v2 you will have to check dedicated Xdebug section from `phpinfo()` output).

Comment: FWIW, You can probably do without specifying the path, and just do `zend_extension=xdebug.so`. I think that works since PHP 5.3.

Comment: @LazyOne You answer are correct, i didn't know that we need to search for PHP API in phpinfo() and get that version for xdebug.so. I thought it must be the first one i found in `locate xdebug.so`. Thanks you.

Comment: @Derick you are right too, i've try the `zend_extension="xdebug.so"` and it's work as well.